# Going from pydantic to aws_cdk.aws_apigateway.JsonSchema?

Tags: python, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, jsonschema, pydantic

Anyone know how to go from a pydantic model to an aws_cdk.aws_apigateway.jsonSchema? We are using it for validation and are looking to convert it to have validation take place at the api gateway. Been looking everywhere and I can't find anything to do this.

I know there is a way to turn pydantic models into a json schema (basic) but not the specific cdk jsonschema.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/JsonSchema.html

https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/

Answer (score 1):

One way how you can do this is by creating construct that implements IModel interface and under the hood creates CfnModel.

```
@jsii.implements(aws_apigateway.IModel)
class CustomModel(Construct):
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        id: str,
        api: "RestApiGateway",
        name: str,
        # you can pass json schema generated by BaseModel.schema()
        schema: dict, 
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id)
        self.schema = schema
        self.model_name = id
        self.api = api
        self.model = aws_apigateway.CfnModel(
            self,
            "Model",
            rest_api_id=api.api.rest_api_id,
            content_type="application/json",
            name=self.model_name,
            schema=self.schema,
        )

    @property
    def model_id(self):
        return self.model_name
```

But take a note that if you have nested models inside your model pydantic will build it using $ref. So in this case you can create main model and nested model, and then use $ref in main model. Here is the format of the $ref link for api gateway models [https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/{rest_api_id}/models/{model_name}](https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/%7Brest_api_id%7D/models/%7Bmodel_name%7D) . Also you need to make main model depend on nested model by using add_dependency method, good article that describe how to create dependencies https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-dependson-relation

Comment: Took me a while to really go through this answer because i was lacking a lot of knowledge. Thanks so much this was SUPER useful.

Comment: So this still doesn't work as the schema needs to be of type aws_cdk.aws_apigateway.JsonSchema. When doing it this way I recieve an error `'Error: Resolution error: Supplied properties not correct for "CfnModelProps"\n  schema: "{\\"$schema\\": \\"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\\", \\"title\\": \\"DummySchema\\", \\"type\\": \\"object\\", \\"properties\\": {\\"id\\": {\\"type\\": \\"string\\"}}}" should be an \'object\'.'` so i think it still needs to go into this type https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/JsonSchema.html